Even when a row meets the conditions in the if statement, the code does not works
Rows with empty leave time should be automatically removed, but the code is not responding.
The contents of the sheet that I am trying to edit are as follows:



company
name
birth
arrivetime
leavetime




AAA
John
1998-09-18
9:23:53
17:23:43


BBB
Michael
1986-03-23
10:32:21



CCC
Kevin
1978-02-12
18:23:51




Michael's row must be deleted, but it doesn't works at all
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arriveTime As Variant
    Dim leaveTime As Variant
    Dim arrivehour As Variant
    
    ' Assign the currently active worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Find the last row
    LastRow = Application.CountA(Range("c3", Range("c" & Rows.Count)))
    
    ' Loop backwards from the last row to row 3
    For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
        arriveTime = ws.Cells(i, 4).value        ' Arrival time (Column D)
        leaveTime = ws.Cells(i, 5).value         ' Leave time (Column E)
        arrivehour = Hour(arriveTime)
        
        ' Check if the leave time is empty
        If leaveTime = "" And arrivehour <= "17" Then   ' If leave time is empty and arrival time is before 17:00
            ws.Rows(i).Delete   ' Delete the row
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Release memory    
    Set ws = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Leave list has been created."

Initially, I thought the issue was with the variable types, but the same problem occurs even with different variable types.

Set a breakpoint on the if statement in the loop and step through the code in the debugger to see if the conditions for the if are ever met. You can do that by watching the values of leaveTime and arrivehour when the if statement is reached (but before it is executed).

First you should define your LastRow variable diferently like LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count or LastRow = Application.CountA(Range("c", Range("c" & Rows.Count))) because as it is right now if you have 10 rows it will leave row 9 and 10 out of the loop.
Second, your condition arrivehour <= "17" should be arrivehour <= 17, I think that's it.

Thank you for your answer
I ran the code with the solution you suggested, but the rows that meet the conditions are still not being removed.
I have no any clues to solve this problem

@Thebusybee it worked for me with the sample data you posted, It was suposed to delete only the michael row, right? Maybe use debug.print to check on the values that are being passed to the condition and excecute it step by step so you can check what is it that is not doing what it should.

Thank you so much for your kindness. While debugging, I revised and rewrote the code, and I was able to solve the problem.

I solved my problem with this code. Just re-coded
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

' Set the active worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Find the last row in column A
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop from the last row to row 3 in reverse order
For i = lastRow To 3 Step -1
    ' Check if departure time is empty
    If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 5)) Then
        ' If check-in time is before 17:00, delete the row
        If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value < TimeValue("17:00:00") Then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Departure list has been created.", vbInformation
End Sub


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
